# Bitshifts Javascript vs Python

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I want to transfer the following python code to javascript:

```
def conv_2c(val, bits):
   return ((1 << bits)+val)



function conv_2c(val, bits){ 
    return ((1 << bits)+val);
}
```

In Python `print(conv_2c(-944,64))` gives me 18446744073709550672 , while 
in JS `console.log(conv_2c(-944,64));` gives me -943 . Why is there a difference?? Is this something to worry about (do the numbers really differ?) or is it a thing of how Python or JS print negative/ two's complement numbers?

Comment: Bitshifting in JavaScript is always done in a 32 bit numbers. So big values can and will overflow.

Comment: sorry, I edited my post... 
So is it possible to handle such big numbers in javascript?

Comment: No, JavaScript numbers are [IEEE 754 floats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point), so the largest representable integer without loosing precision is [9007199254740991](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER).

Comment: ^ Although there are [libraries that exist](http://mathjs.org/docs/datatypes/bignumbers.html) to handle higher precision numbers.

Comment: @poke then again, you will NOT be able to bitshift numbers that big - the biggest one you will be able to do is 2147483647 (2^31 - 1). If you go over, you immediately get the wrong result due to an overflow.

Comment: @vlaz Never said otherwise. My “no” in that comment was in response to “is it possible to handle such big numbers in javascript”. That doesn’t take into account the *additional* restrictions on bit shifting.